# How to include wsdl files into the project?

Tags: .net, web-services, wsdl

I am writing a wcf application.During a Visual Studio build, I need to include wsdl files into the project. How to do it? I know disco.exe is able to download these files.

Comment: Where are the `wsdl` files supposed to come from?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio you add a Webservice as an Reference.

- In Solution Explorer, right-click the name of the project to add the Web service to and then click Add Web Reference.
- The Add Web Reference dialog box is displayed.
- In the URL box, enter the URL of the Web service to use. If you do not know the URL, use the links in the browse pane to locate the Web service you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx(v=vs.80).aspx